# Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$scope.$storage.match_id')

Tags: angularjs

I've already looked around the web for hours but I can't find any solution. I use Angular with LocalStorage to get the match_id.

I have the following code snippet, which throws me `Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$scope.$storage.match_id')`

```
app.controller('confirmMatchCtrl', ["$scope", "$filter", "$routeParams", "$translate", "$location", "Data", "$http", "onlineStatus", "$localStorage",
function ($scope, $filter, $routeParams, $translate, $location, Data, $http, onlineStatus, $localStorage) {
    var id = $scope.$storage.match_id;
```

Maybe someone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: I think you are missing `$scope.$storage = $localStorage;` somewhere

Answer (score 0):

**You need to assign the storage first and also put an additionaly null/undefined check to avoid such situations.**

```
app.controller('confirmMatchCtrl', ["$scope", "$filter", "$routeParams", "$translate", "$location", "Data", "$http", "onlineStatus", "$localStorage",
   function ($scope, $filter, $routeParams, $translate, $location, Data, $http, onlineStatus, $localStorage) {
       $scope.$storage = $localStorage;
       if($scope.$storage){
         var id = $scope.$storage.match_id;
       }
}
```